# Draw svg rect issues: infinity lenght and blink

Tags: javascript, svg, draw

I'm trying to draw a  with the mouse. When the mouse is moving and pressed, it draws the area, but during it, the area blinks. In the console, when setAttribute adds width and height, sometimes appears "Infinity" and I think that it's the problem, but I don't understand why, because when I comment this line   `configRectSize(document.getElementById(rectId), width, height);`, all numbers are correct.

I have other issue with drawing. When currentX or currentY coordinates are lower than initX or initY, I change x and y rect coordinates to be able to draw it in other direction (not only left to right and top to bottom) but sometimes the rect desappears or changes to other diferent coordinates.

Could you help me please? It's driving me crazy!

Thanks a lot!

https://jsfiddle.net/albaruz/scegfom8/23/

```js
var ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svgId = "SvgId";
var image = document.getElementById("PlanImage");

function initSVG(SvgName, container) {
  svg = document.createElementNS(ns, "svg");
  var svgId = SvgName;
  svg.setAttributeNS(null, "id", svgId);
  container.appendChild(svg);

  return svgId;
}

function calculateSVGSize(SvgName, container) {
  var imageWidth = container.clientWidth;
  var imageHeight = container.clientHeight;
  var aspectRatio = (imageHeight * 100) / imageWidth;
  document
    .getElementById(SvgName)
    .setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 100 " + aspectRatio);
}

function configRectSize(rect, width, height) {
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", width);
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", height);
}

function getY(rect, y) {
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
}

function getX(rect, x) {
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
}

function configRectCoords(rect, x, y) {
  getY(rect, y);
  getX(rect, x);
}

function configRect(name, width, height, x, y, isBooking) {
  var rect = document.getElementById(name);
  configRectSize(rect, width, height);
  configRectCoords(rect, x, y);
  rect.setAttributeNS(
    null,
    "fill",
    isBooking ? "rgba(0,265, 0, .3)" : "rgba(265, 0, 0, .3)"
  );
  rect.onclick = function() {
    alert(name);
  };
}

function createRect(SvgName, name) {
  var rect = document.createElementNS(ns, "rect");
  rect.id = name;
  document.getElementById(SvgName).appendChild(rect);
}

function drawRect(SvgName, rectId) {
  var svg = document.getElementById(SvgName);
  var rect = document.getElementById(rectId);
  var isMouseDown = false;
  var isMouseMoving = true;
  var initX;
  var initY;

  var handleMouseMove = function(e, initX, initY) {
    var currentX = ((e.offsetX * 100) / e.target.clientWidth).toFixed(2);
    var currentY = ((e.offsetY * 100) / e.target.clientHeight).toFixed(2);

    var width = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(initX - (currentX), 2)).toFixed(2);
    var height = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(initY - (currentY), 2)).toFixed(2);
    
    console.log(`currentX: ${currentX}`);
    console.log(`currentY: ${currentY}`);
    console.log(`width: ${width}`);
    console.log(`height: ${height}`);

   if (currentY < initY && currentX < initX) {

      configRectCoords(
        document.getElementById(rectId),
        currentX,
        currentY
      );
    } 
    else if (currentX < initX)
      configRectCoords(document.getElementById(rectId), currentX, initY);

    else if (currentY < initY)
      configRectCoords(document.getElementById(rectId), initX, currentY);
    else
      configRectCoords(document.getElementById(rectId), initX, initY);


    configRectSize(document.getElementById(rectId), width, height);


 
  };

  svg.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  
  
    isMouseDown = true;
    console.log("estoy apretando");
    initX = ((e.offsetX * 100) / e.target.clientWidth).toFixed(2);
    initY = ((e.offsetY * 100) / e.target.clientHeight).toFixed(2);
    console.log(`initX: ${initX}`);
    console.log(`initY: ${initY}`);

    //Initialize RectCreation
    if (!document.getElementById(rectId)) {
      createRect(SvgName, rectId);
    }

    configRectCoords(document.getElementById(rectId), initX, initY);
    configRectSize(document.getElementById(rectId), 0, 0);


  });

  svg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (!isMouseDown) return;
    e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation(); 
    console.log("me estoy moviendo");
    handleMouseMove(e, initX, initY);
  });

  svg.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    isMouseDown = false;
  });
}
initSVG(svgId, DeskInteraction);

image.onload = function() {
  calculateSVGSize(svgId, DeskInteraction);
};

drawRect(svgId, DeskInteraction);
```

```css
  .plan-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 500px;
    }
    .plan-wrapper img {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .plan-wrapper .plan-interaction {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 10;
    }
```

```html
  <div data-container="" class="plan-wrapper" id="PlanContainer">
    <img data-image="" class="plan-image" id="PlanImage" style="margin-left: auto" src="https://www.jcadg.com/2d-3d-floor-plan/images/mobile/gold.jpg" />
    <div data-container="" class="plan-interaction" id="DeskInteraction"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please restrict yourself to asking one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The way you calculated the `x` and `y` coordinates is not correct, even if you are doing it for any DOM element. In the case of an `svg` element (which you are attaching the handle to), you would also need to take into account any transformation on the coordinates. This is simple with `matrixTransform` and `getScreenCTM`. I have added a function called `getSVGCoords` to your script and called it to calculate both the init and the current coordinates:

```js
var ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svgId = "SvgId";
var image = document.getElementById("PlanImage");

function initSVG(SvgName, container) {
  svg = document.createElementNS(ns, "svg");
  var svgId = SvgName;
  svg.setAttributeNS(null, "id", svgId);
  container.appendChild(svg);

  return svgId;
}

function calculateSVGSize(SvgName, container) {
  var imageWidth = container.clientWidth;
  var imageHeight = container.clientHeight;
  var aspectRatio = (imageHeight * 100) / imageWidth;
  document
    .getElementById(SvgName)
    .setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 100 " + aspectRatio);
}

function configRectSize(rect, width, height) {
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "width", width);
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "height", height);
}

function getY(rect, y) {
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "y", y);
}

function getX(rect, x) {
  rect.setAttributeNS(null, "x", x);
}

function configRectCoords(rect, x, y) {
  getY(rect, y);
  getX(rect, x);
}

function configRect(name, width, height, x, y, isBooking) {
  var rect = document.getElementById(name);
  configRectSize(rect, width, height);
  configRectCoords(rect, x, y);
  rect.setAttributeNS(
    null,
    "fill",
    isBooking ? "rgba(0,265, 0, .3)" : "rgba(265, 0, 0, .3)"
  );
  rect.onclick = function() {
    alert(name);
  };
}

function createRect(SvgName, name) {
  var rect = document.createElementNS(ns, "rect");
  rect.id = name;
  document.getElementById(SvgName).appendChild(rect);
}
function getSVGCoords(s, ev){
  var pt = s.createSVGPoint();
    pt.x = ev.clientX;
    pt.y = ev.clientY;
    var loc = pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
  return loc
}
   
function drawRect(SvgName, rectId) {
  var svg = document.getElementById(SvgName);
  var rect = document.getElementById(rectId);
  var isMouseDown = false;
  var isMouseMoving = true;
  var initX;
  var initY;

  var handleMouseMove = function(e, initX, initY) {
    // Insertion HERE
    var loc = getSVGCoords(svg, e);
    var currentX = loc.x;
    var currentY = loc.y;
    //
    var width = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(initX - (currentX), 2)).toFixed(2);
    var height = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(initY - (currentY), 2)).toFixed(2);
    
    console.log(`currentX: ${currentX}`);
    console.log(`currentY: ${currentY}`);
    console.log(`width: ${width}`);
    console.log(`height: ${height}`);

   if (currentY < initY && currentX < initX) {

      configRectCoords(
        document.getElementById(rectId),
        currentX,
        currentY
      );
    } 
    else if (currentX < initX)
      configRectCoords(document.getElementById(rectId), currentX, initY);

    else if (currentY < initY)
      configRectCoords(document.getElementById(rectId), initX, currentY);
    else
      configRectCoords(document.getElementById(rectId), initX, initY);


    configRectSize(document.getElementById(rectId), width, height);


 
  };

  svg.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
  
  
    isMouseDown = true;
    console.log("estoy apretando");
    var loc = getSVGCoords(svg, e);
    initX = loc.x;
    initY = loc.y;
    console.log(`initX: ${initX}`);
    console.log(`initY: ${initY}`);

    //Initialize RectCreation
    if (!document.getElementById(rectId)) {
      createRect(SvgName, rectId);
    }

    configRectCoords(document.getElementById(rectId), initX, initY);
    configRectSize(document.getElementById(rectId), 0, 0);


  });

  svg.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (!isMouseDown) return;
    e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation(); 
    console.log("me estoy moviendo");
    handleMouseMove(e, initX, initY);
  });

  svg.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    isMouseDown = false;
  });
}
initSVG(svgId, DeskInteraction);

image.onload = function() {
  calculateSVGSize(svgId, DeskInteraction);
};

drawRect(svgId, DeskInteraction);
```

```css
  .plan-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 500px;
    }
    .plan-wrapper img {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .plan-wrapper .plan-interaction {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 10;
    }
```

```html
  <div data-container="" class="plan-wrapper" id="PlanContainer">
    <img data-image="" class="plan-image" id="PlanImage" style="margin-left: auto" src="https://www.jcadg.com/2d-3d-floor-plan/images/mobile/gold.jpg" />
    <div data-container="" class="plan-interaction" id="DeskInteraction"></div>
  </div>
```